# PHP Storm, identação

Tags: php, phpstorm

Olá, alguém sabe como mudar, ao identar automaticamente o código no PHP Storm as chaves não pularem a linha?

[image: Gostaria dele assim:]

[image: Só que após a formatação ele fica assim]

Answer (score 3):

Você pode alterar isso em:

```
"File" > "Settings" > "Code Style" > "PHP" > "Wrapping and Braces"
```

Terá o seguinte campo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enquanto estiver "Next line" ele irá pular a linha, se estiver "End of line" manterá na mesma linha.